# Curl CONNECTTIMEOUT question

Tags: c++, curl

If you curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15); and 15 seconds passes and no connection is made, what will happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this mailing list thread](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2004-01/0165.html), [the documentation for `curl_easy_setopt`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) and the documentation for [`curl_easy_perform`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html), the call to `curl_easy_perform` will fail with error code `CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEOUTED` as defined in `<curl/curl.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend that you pass a long instead of an int.  (They aren't always the same size, and curl_easy_setopt expects a long.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15L);
```